# Running multiple threads concurrently in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to run two threads concurrently where one prints numbers 1 to 500 whereas the another prints numbers 501 to 1000. The output must show the concurrency.

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: You have our permission to start coding. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Simply search producer consumer on google..

Comment: Isn't that one liner? `Stream.of(0, 500).parallel().forEach(start -> IntStream.rangeClosed(start + 1, start + 500).forEach(Main::printAndSleep));` where `printAndSleep(int it) { System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + it); try { TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1); } catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new IllegalStateException("Naah, we have to catch this inside lambdas.");`
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code. Main thread prints numbers from 1 to 500 and other thread prints from there on to 1000.

```
public class Test  implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Test());
        t.start();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <=500 ; i++)
            System.out.println("Main Thread printing "+i);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=501; i <=1000 ; i++) 
            System.out.println("Thread 1 printing "+i);
    } 
}
```